# Wordpress + SSL + Varnish + Pound

Tags: ssl, varnish

Hello Im try install a SSL certificate with Pound and Varnish for a Wordpress site. The Proxy is an independent server, and has been running fine (few years) with varnish. I've used pound and this setup (90% the same) on many custom sites, so am sure the configuration there is correct and the SSL certificate is valid also.

```
Setup = http+https -> Proxy (Varnish / Pound (Certificate)->Varnish) -> Webserver
```

the `https` call works before I try and rename the site URL to `https` and have tried modifying the `.htaccess` file to force `https` but is creating a redirect loop and breaks. It also creates the same loop with just the site url set as `https://`

I've checked `default.vcl` and that is working fine and has no redirect conditions - was hoping the varnish redirect setup for a primary domain would allow me to ignore redirecting using varnish as the server has a number of domains running against it.

Where else can I look to check the redirect and ensure they are correct i.e. Must be `http` -> `https` -> `http` -> `https`.

Bit tricky to find the source of the redirect, any ideas?